# cpu high after visual studio 2015 RTM openning an cordova project

Tags: cordova, typescript, visual-studio-2015

The project source is at https://github.com/Yaojian/Ionic-TypeScript-Starter/ .

I forked https://github.com/Justin-Credible/Ionic-TypeScript-Starter/ and tried to create a visual studio project using steps decribed at : https://github.com/Yaojian/Ionic-TypeScript-Starter/wiki/IonicTemplate-VisualStudio

The project file works fine on building or debuging, but the VisualStudio IDE runs at high CPU occupation ( >20% on my mac book pro) without any activity.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong, The high CPU is caused by Resharper solution wide analysis.

Sorry.